# Functions.php Wordpress syntax error

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm implementing Wordpress (from scratch) in a custom design and I'm having some issues with the functions.php file.

I don't have any plugins added to my website that current hosted locally with MAMP.

There are three parts of the code: one to create custom size of thumbnails, another to fix a media library error and another to create 3 different sidebar widgets.

I added the first two sections (thumbnail + media library) and everything worked fine, but after adding the last part (sidebar) the media library doesn't work again. When deleting the sidebar code, the media library works again. So these three parts are interfering and canceling each other out somehow. 
I'm pretty sure my mistake is of syntax... Here is the full code:

```
<?php 
// Add custom size of thumbnails 
if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) { 
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
    set_post_thumbnail_size( 150, 150, true ); // default Post Thumbnail dimensions (cropped)
    add_image_size( 'another-size', 600, 400 ); // Not Cropped (additional sizes) size doesn't matter because we're adding "full"
 }

// Fixes Media Library error (without this it's not possible to add images or manage it – it just appears empty)

function ms_image_editor_default_to_gd( $editors ) {
$gd_editor = 'WP_Image_Editor_GD';
$editors = array_diff( $editors, array( $gd_editor ) );
array_unshift( $editors, $gd_editor );
return $editors;
}
add_filter( 'wp_image_editors', 'ms_image_editor_default_to_gd' );

?>


<?php

// Created three different sidebars and allows user to edit their content as widgets

if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') ) {

   register_sidebar(array(
   'name'          => 'column 1',
   'before_widget' => '',
   'after_widget' => '',
   'before_title' => '<h2>',
   'after_title' => '</h2>'

   ));

     register_sidebar(array(
   'name'          => 'column 2',
   'before_widget' => '',
   'after_widget' => '',
   'before_title' => '<h2>',
   'after_title' => '</h2>'
   ));

       register_sidebar(array(
   'name'          => 'column 3',
   'before_widget' => '',
   'after_widget' => '',
   'before_title' => '<h2>',
   'after_title' => '</h2>'
   ));

}?>
```

Comment: You should open php tag once. delete |
?>
<?php   this part of code after add_filter( 'wp_image_editors', 'ms_image_editor_default_to_gd' ); and try.

Comment: What doesn't work in the media library.  I added your code to my functions.php file and everything is rendering.

Comment: Without that code the media library doesn't load (it's keeps on loading forever). I got the code from here: https://ideasandpixels.com/wordpress-media-library-not-working-solution/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, maybe you should use only one `<?php ?>` section

```
<?php 
// Add custom size of thumbnails 
if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) { 
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
    set_post_thumbnail_size( 150, 150, true ); // default Post Thumbnail dimensions (cropped)
    add_image_size( 'another-size', 600, 400 ); // Not Cropped (additional sizes) size doesn't matter because we're adding "full"
 }

// Fixes Media Library error (without this it's not possible to add images or manage it – it just appears empty)

function ms_image_editor_default_to_gd( $editors ) {
$gd_editor = 'WP_Image_Editor_GD';
$editors = array_diff( $editors, array( $gd_editor ) );
array_unshift( $editors, $gd_editor );
return $editors;
}
add_filter( 'wp_image_editors', 'ms_image_editor_default_to_gd' );

// Created three different sidebars and allows user to edit their content as widgets

if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') ) {

   register_sidebar(array(
   'name'          => 'column 1',
   'before_widget' => '',
   'after_widget' => '',
   'before_title' => '<h2>',
   'after_title' => '</h2>'

   ));

     register_sidebar(array(
   'name'          => 'column 2',
   'before_widget' => '',
   'after_widget' => '',
   'before_title' => '<h2>',
   'after_title' => '</h2>'
   ));

       register_sidebar(array(
   'name'          => 'column 3',
   'before_widget' => '',
   'after_widget' => '',
   'before_title' => '<h2>',
   'after_title' => '</h2>'
   ));

}?>
```

Comment: It's not semantically correct having the opening and closing tags but removing them doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: This seems to have fixed it! Both the sidebar widgets and the media library are now working, and the custom thumbnails are the correct size!

Comment: @Wellosova Glad to help you, please, vote for my answer if it really helped you )